# Pre install some required dependancy and perform some settings while creating new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio is there any way, if I create new project then some most required dependancies like **Retrofit**, **Logging Library like Timber** should automatically implemented in build.gradle file.

Other thing like

```
dexOptions {
        incremental = true
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
    }
```

should automatically applied in build.gradle

In **Android Manifest**, Most required permission like **Storage** or **Internet permission** will be automatically applied.

Like I can customise it according to my need, what should need to be pre-filled in gradle file or ManifestFile so I don't need to add everything from scratch.

Comment: I suggest you to create a GitHub repository with all the required things. Whenever need to start a new project, just clone it using Android Studio. Let android studio do the rest.

Comment: Yes might be this is good idea, just need to refactor package name! Thanks